# Simple pygame program to fix

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to Python and I have modified dodger (here's the link http://inventwithpython.com/dodger.py) to add ''goodies'', sprites similar to the baddies, but that give you score when you touch them; instead of killing you as the baddies do.
(I have made a change at the start with easygui too, but it works fine).

I am really confused as this code works (I mean this code **starts**) but the goodies don't appear, like if I didn't put them in at all. I have tried to figure out by myself what the problem is but I haven't found it. The source code is long but there are some comments to make it more readable. I think that the multimedia files are right because it doesn't give me error messages.

Here you have the not working program:

```
import pygame, random, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import easygui

#Message to make the user decide the hardness of the game
msg = 'Inserisci un numero da 1 a 20\n per la difficoltà: \n1 = Semplice\n 20 = Impossibile'
title = 'Difficoltà'

#Message to make the user decide the colour of the background of the game
Difficoltà = easygui.enterbox(msg,title)
msg   = "Quale colore preferisci fra questi come sfondo?"
choices = ["Nero","Blu","Verde"]
COLORESCELTODALLUTENTE = easygui.buttonbox(msg,choices=choices)

#Unused Values as it runs in fullscreen mode
WINDOWWIDTH = 800
WINDOWHEIGHT = 600

#The text is white
TEXTCOLOR = (255, 255, 255)

#Changes the colour of the background according to the choice of the user
if COLORESCELTODALLUTENTE == 'Nero':
    BACKGROUNDCOLOR = (0, 0, 0)
elif COLORESCELTODALLUTENTE == 'Blu':
    BACKGROUNDCOLOR = (36, 68, 212)
elif COLORESCELTODALLUTENTE == 'Verde':
    BACKGROUNDCOLOR = (36, 237, 52)

#Frames per second the game will run at
FPS = 40

#Description of the baddies
baddie_type_1MINSIZE = 20
baddie_type_1MAXSIZE = 40
baddie_type_1MINSPEED = 4
baddie_type_1MAXSPEED = 5
ADDNEWbaddie_type_1RATE = 21 - int(Difficoltà)

#Description of the goddies
goddie_type_1MINSIZE = 20
goddie_type_1MAXSIZE = 40
goddie_type_1MINSPEED = 4
goddie_type_1MAXSPEED = 5
ADDNEWgoddie_type_1RATE = 10

#How fast you move with the arrows
PLAYERMOVERATE = 5

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def waitForPlayerToPressKey():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE: # pressing escape quits
                    terminate()
                return

def playerHasHitbaddie_type_1(playerRect, baddies_type_1):
    for b in baddies_type_1:
        if playerRect.colliderect(b['rect_b']):
            return True
    return False

def playerHasHitgoddie_type_1(playerRect, goddies_type_1):
    for g in goddies_type_1:
        if playerRect.colliderect(g['rect_g']):
            return True
    return False

def drawText(text, font, surface, x, y):
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, TEXTCOLOR)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

# set up pygame, the window, and the mouse cursor
pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
#This down here is windowed mode
#windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
#This down here is fullscreen mode
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.display.set_caption('Dodger')
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

# set up fonts
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

# set up sounds
gameOverSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('Gameover.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.load('Background.mp3')

# set up images
playerImage = pygame.image.load('Player.png')
playerRect = playerImage.get_rect()
baddie_type_1Image = pygame.image.load('Baddie_type_1.png')
goddie_type_1Image = pygame.image.load('Goddie_type_1.png')

# show the "Start" screen
drawText('Dodger', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
drawText('Press a key to start.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 30, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
pygame.display.update()
waitForPlayerToPressKey()


topScore = 0
while True:
    # set up the start of the game
    baddies_type_1 = []
    goddies_type_1 = []
    score = 0
    playerRect.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, WINDOWHEIGHT - 50)
    moveLeft = moveRight = moveUp = moveDown = False
    reverseCheat = slowCheat = False
    baddie_type_1AddCounter = 0
    goddie_type_1AddCounter = 0
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

    while True: # the game loop runs while the game part is playing
        score += 1 # increase score

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == ord('z'):
                    reverseCheat = True
                if event.key == ord('x'):
                    slowCheat = True
                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    moveRight = False
                    moveLeft = True
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    moveLeft = False
                    moveRight = True
                if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                    moveDown = False
                    moveUp = True
                if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                    moveUp = False
                    moveDown = True

            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == ord('z'):
                    reverseCheat = False
                    score = 0
                if event.key == ord('x'):
                    slowCheat = False
                    score = 0
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        terminate()

                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    moveLeft = False
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    moveRight = False
                if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                    moveUp = False
                if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                    moveDown = False

            if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                # If the mouse moves, move the player where the cursor is.
                playerRect.move_ip(event.pos[0] - playerRect.centerx, event.pos[1] - playerRect.centery)

        # ize is for size
        # Add new baddies_type_1 at the top of the screen, if needed.
        if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
            baddie_type_1AddCounter += 1
        if baddie_type_1AddCounter == ADDNEWbaddie_type_1RATE:
            baddie_type_1AddCounter = 0
            baddies_type_1ize = random.randint(baddie_type_1MINSIZE, baddie_type_1MAXSIZE)
            newbaddie_type_1 = {'rect_b': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH-baddies_type_1ize), 0 - baddies_type_1ize, baddies_type_1ize, baddies_type_1ize),
                        'speed_b': random.randint(baddie_type_1MINSPEED, baddie_type_1MAXSPEED),
                        'surface_b':pygame.transform.scale(baddie_type_1Image, (baddies_type_1ize, baddies_type_1ize)),
                        }

            baddies_type_1.append(newbaddie_type_1)

        # ize is for size
        # Add new goddies_type_1 at the top of the screen, if needed.
        if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
            goddie_type_1AddCounter += 1
        if goddie_type_1AddCounter == ADDNEWgoddie_type_1RATE:
            goddie_type_1AddCounter = 0
            goddies_type_1ize = random.randint(goddie_type_1MINSIZE, goddie_type_1MAXSIZE)
            newgoddie_type_1 = {'rect_g': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH-goddies_type_1ize), 0 - goddies_type_1ize, goddies_type_1ize, goddies_type_1ize),
                        'speed_g': random.randint(goddie_type_1MINSPEED, goddie_type_1MAXSPEED),
                        'surface_g':pygame.transform.scale(goddie_type_1Image, (goddies_type_1ize, goddies_type_1ize)),
                        }

        # Move the player around.
        if moveLeft and playerRect.left > 0:
            playerRect.move_ip(-1 * PLAYERMOVERATE, 0)
        if moveRight and playerRect.right < WINDOWWIDTH:
            playerRect.move_ip(PLAYERMOVERATE, 0)
        if moveUp and playerRect.top > 0:
            playerRect.move_ip(0, -1 * PLAYERMOVERATE)
        if moveDown and playerRect.bottom < WINDOWHEIGHT:
            playerRect.move_ip(0, PLAYERMOVERATE)

        # Move the mouse cursor to match the player.
        pygame.mouse.set_pos(playerRect.centerx, playerRect.centery)

        # Move the baddies_type_1 down.
        for b in baddies_type_1:
            if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
                b['rect_b'].move_ip(0, b['speed_b'])
            elif reverseCheat:
                b['rect_b'].move_ip(0, -5)
            elif slowCheat:
                b['rect_b'].move_ip(0, 1)

        # Move the goddies_type_1 down.
        for g in goddies_type_1:
            if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
                g['rect_g'].move_ip(0, g['speed_g'])
            elif reverseCheat:
                g['rect_g'].move_ip(0, -5)
            elif slowCheat:
                g['rect_g'].move_ip(0, 1)


         # Delete baddies_type_1 that have fallen past the bottom.
        for b in baddies_type_1[:]:
            if b['rect_b'].top > WINDOWHEIGHT:
                baddies_type_1.remove(b)

        # Delete goddies_type_1 that have fallen past the bottom.
        for g in goddies_type_1[:]:
            if g['rect_g'].top > WINDOWHEIGHT:
                goddies_type_1.remove(g)

        # Draw the game world on the window.
        windowSurface.fill(BACKGROUNDCOLOR)

        # Draw the score and top score.
        drawText('Score: %s' % (score), font, windowSurface, 10, 0)
        drawText('Top Score: %s' % (topScore), font, windowSurface, 10, 40)

        # Draw the player's rectangle
        windowSurface.blit(playerImage, playerRect)

        # Draw each baddie_type_1
        for b in baddies_type_1:
            windowSurface.blit(b['surface_b'], b['rect_b'])

        # Draw each goddie_type_1
        for g in goddies_type_1:
            windowSurface.blit(g['surface_g'], g['rect_g'])


        pygame.display.update()

        # Check if any of the baddies_type_1 have hit the player.
        if playerHasHitbaddie_type_1(playerRect, baddies_type_1):
            if score > topScore:
                topScore = score # set new top score
            break

        # Check if any of the goddies_type_1 have hit the player.
        if playerHasHitgoddie_type_1(playerRect, goddies_type_1):
            score = score + 200

        #Frapes of the game
        mainClock.tick(FPS)

    # Stop the game and show the "Game Over" screen.
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    gameOverSound.play()

    drawText('GAME OVER', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
    drawText('Press a key to play again.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 80, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
    pygame.display.update()
    waitForPlayerToPressKey()

    gameOverSound.stop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  To better and more quickly answer your question, you should consider reducing the code you've posted to a minimal demonstration of the problem. Please see http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: My problem is that the error may be everywhere! Because the programme doesen't give me an error message but only 'ignores' the 'goddies' I have no idea where to look for it.

Comment: That's even more of a reason to reduce it.  By doing that, you will likely find the answer yourself, and learn well by doing.  You can add `print` statements to more easily see the state of variables that may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `# Add new baddies_type_1 at the top of the screen, if needed.` code, it looks like you actually add the baddie with this line:

`baddies_type_1.append(newbaddie_type_1)`

You don't appear to be doing that with your goodies code.  Try adding:

`goddies_type_1.append(newgoddie_type_1)`

after your `# Add new goddies_type_1 at the top of the screen, if needed.` if statements.

Also, you spelled `goodies` as `goddies` throughout your code.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question so quickly and clearly!